# Bootstrap modal open on click and stays open for 10 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open modal on click, in modal i have form and submit button. When user fulfill form i want to display message if submit is true or fals and to close modal automatically after 10 sec.

This is my code for now, everything works great but my modal opens even i dont click on button.

HTML Code:

```
<a href="#insert_poslovni" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" id="insert_p">Unos</a>
```

JS Code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        //instantiate your content as modal
        $("#insert_poslovni").modal({
            //modal options here, like keyboard: false for e.g.
        });

    setTimeout(function() {$("#insert_poslovni").modal("hide");}, 10000);;

        //show the modal when dom is ready
        $("#insert_poslovni").modal("show");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't think you need the last line if you are using `data-toggle`. That line is causing the modal to be displayed on page load.

Comment: if i remove data-toggle, modal will not open

Comment: @Vorda, I just edited, my answer, please check it out. On submit button in the modal, it waits 10 seconds, then closes

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
$(function(){
    $("#insert_poslovni").modal({ //modal options });

    $("#submitbuttonid").on('click', function(e){
        setTimeout(function() {$("#insert_poslovni").modal("hide");}, 10000);

    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This only starts the code after clicking the button
you could also add the same function to the close button by setting and id

http://jsfiddle.net/ge0g8kbc/25/

Comment: that works, but i want modal to stay open after i clicked submit for 10 sec

Comment: still the same, model opens i fulfill form and press submit and modal closes...i need to stay open for 10 sec

Comment: when we want to hide it first time then it should tell it to hide again in 10 seconds. The data attribute flag prevents us being stuck in a loop

Comment: I don't know if i am doing something wrong but it is still the same, when i click the button submit in modal the modal closes instantly.?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle example?

Comment: something like this, only i dont have database on jsfiddle...i click on unos and modal opent, i enter fulfill everything and when i press Unos/submit i want modal to stay open for 10sec

http://jsfiddle.net/pzaLqxL2/

Answer (score 0):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/148/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.open').on('click', function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
    $('.submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }, 10000);
    });
});

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg open">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using your js Fiddle, heres the updated working version: http://jsfiddle.net/pzaLqxL2/2/

`e.preventDefault()` is lower cased "p"

```
$(function(){
    $("#insert_p").click(function(){
        // rest of code in here

        $("#insert_poslovni").on("hide.bs.modal", function(e){
            if($("#insert_poslovni").data("prevented") !== "prevented"){
                $("#insert_poslovni").data("prevented", "prevented");
                e.preventDefault();
                setTimeout(function() {$("#insert_poslovni").modal("hide");}, 10000);
            }
            else{
                $("#insert_poslovni").data("prevented", "");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: still the same! i uploaded my app online you can check it ! go on Poslovni korisnici and press Unos, after you insert data in lables and press Unos it needs to stay open
http://croatianinn.comuv.com/index.php

Comment: you have to use the code in my previous solution then, and make it on click of the button in the modal `$('.submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }, 10000);
    });`
 and then do the code that submits the form, cause the code works for closing the modal with the "x". you'll have to interrupt your submission code to place the delay in it